# Intent For opening google maps with specific search text

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm creating a local guide app on android, and I want to set an onItemClickListener to my array that will open google maps with filled search text. For example: In shopping category, there are stores like ZARA H&M. So, I want to create an Intent that will open google maps with search text "ZARA near me" etc.

Can anyone help me with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the lat, lon of the area you are interested like so:

// Search for restaurants in San Francisco

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194?q=restaurants");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Or by address like so:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain+View, California");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Taken from [the Google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents).

Comment: Hello The_Martian, thanks for your response, the second one worked for me. Have a nice day